# Weather API how to get data through JSON with 9 hours gap

Tags: android, json

I have [a weather API](http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=a7ae9451110d406489f112831171408&q=hyderabad&days=10) and I want forecast temperature with 9 hours gap according to our current date and time list

If current time is 12:00 then it should display temperature of 9:00 then 18:00 then next day temp at 3:00 hour then 12:00 then 21:00 like this upto 5 days using webservice.

```
ArrayList<ForecastWeather> product_new_arrayy = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int z = 0; z < arrJson.length(); z++)
        {
        JSONObject object3e = arrJson.getJSONObject(z);
        Log.v("hour", object3e.toString());

        JSONArray houre = object3e.getJSONArray("hour");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "" + hour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // int x=foo;


        stimee = object3e.getString("date");


        List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int x=0; x<houre.length(); x++) {


        JSONObject persone = (JSONObject) houre.get(x);


        timee = persone.getString("time");

        answers.add(timee);






        String[] daysArray = new String[] {"sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"};
        String day = "";

        int dayOfWeek =0;

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date datee;
        try {
        datee = formatter.parse(timee);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(datee);
        dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
        if (dayOfWeek < 0) {
        dayOfWeek += 7;
        }
        day = daysArray[dayOfWeek];
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ForecastWeather fw = new ForecastWeather();
        fw.setTemperature(persone.getString("temp_c") + (char) 0x00B0 + "C" );
        timee = persone.getString("time");
        String timeappoch =persone.getString("time_epoch");

        int timea = Integer.parseInt(timeappoch);
        int addd= timea+32400000;

        Log.v("Add",""+ addd );


        fw.setTime(day + "\n\n" + timee  );
        product_new_arrayy.add(fw);





        Log.v("array", timee );
//                            
        jsonArrayResponsee  += "Day at: " + day +" " + timee +" \n\n" + "Temp:" + namee + (char) 0x00B0 + "C" + "\n\n";



        }
        Log.v("HHH", answers.toString());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String datetime = dateformat.format(cal.getTime());

        if(answers.contains(datetime)){



        }


        }
        ArrayList <ForecastWeather> all = new ArrayList <>();
        all.addAll(product_new_arrayy);

        showAllProducts(all);
```

I m getting all days and every hour temperature but i want 9 hour gap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASynk for short network calls . but why to have 9 hours of gap. With asynk , you can get json response every time you open the app. So that your information will be much significant and efficient.

Comment: Yes i can get network calls using async or volley but from json i need to show temperature forecast in weather app i.e future time with 9 hours gap

Comment: Does the future estimated climate also consisted in that APIs.

Comment: Then u can use same asynk for getting whole climate information and then u can parse it separately where you want . I mean in  future time (text view I'd u gave to future estimated climate)

Comment: I suggest you to upload your XML code to get clear information about ids you gave

Comment: i am getting all days temperature in a string with every hour but not with 9 hours gap